# Change ASP.NET_sessionid cookie path using SessionIDManager

Tags: iis, cookies, web-config, session-cookies, session-state

I'm renaming the cookie and made it to target to a different path, rather than targeting to a default path "/".

Below is the web.config settings:

```
<sessionState sessionIDManagerType="MyNamespace.MySessionIDManager" cookieName="AppCookie"/>
```

Below is the backend class used to create the cookie:

```
 public class MySessionIDManager : SessionIDManager, ISessionIDManager
{
    void ISessionIDManager.SaveSessionID(HttpContext context, string id, out bool redirected, out bool cookieAdded)
    {
        base.SaveSessionID(context, id, out redirected, out cookieAdded);

        if (cookieAdded)
        {
            var name = "AppCookie";
            var cookie = context.Response.Cookies[name];
            cookie.Path = "/Forms";
        }
    }
}
```

This fix is working fine for me locally. The cookie is successfully pointing to the given path i.e "/Forms".

[image]

But when I deploy my application to IIS, I'm not able to login to the application.
It is not throwing any error, but not allowing me to login to the web application.

If I use to below web.config settings, it is working fine.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" cookieName="AppCookie" />
```

Please let me know what issue it is causing in the IIS.
Any input is much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Thanks and Regards,
Dada.

Comment: Clear the entire history in browser the js file,and cache is stored on our browser when we change anything on the common file like js and other it won't refresh, i hope it will work

Comment: Hi @Karthikcbe tried clearing the history but still facing the same issue. After entering the credentials and click enter, the page just refreshes and credentials are cleared.

Comment: I would suggest you temporarily use the `cookieName="AppCookie"` and then try to print the `cookie.Path` and see what value it reflects on the IIS and on your local dev machine. It could help us know whether there is any issue in the assignment of the Cookie path value.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT, you mean to remove the cookie path I'm assigning in the MySessionIDManager Class? If I remove the path assignment it'll point to the root i.e "/" both locally and in the IIS. Please let me know any other steps if you want me to follow.

Comment: No, you could keep that path in the MySessionIDManager Class but in Web.Config use `cookieName="AppCookie"`. Then try to print the Cookie path value.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I'm already using 'cookieName="AppCookie"' in the web.config, as mentioned in the question above.  And it is pointing to given path as shown in the screenshot attached.

Comment: You could try to print the Cookie path and see whether it is the correct path.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Locally it is pointing to the correct path, over IIS it is still pointing to "/".

Comment: When you host the site on IIS, does the cookie name also get changed? I have doubts whether the new cookie is generated or not. I would suggest trying to clear all the cookies for the site. then try to visit the site and see whether the cookie is generated. Also check, whether there is any error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue with the below piece of code;

```
public class CookieManager : SessionIDManager, ISessionIDManager
{
    void ISessionIDManager.SaveSessionID(HttpContext context, string id, out bool redirected, out bool cookieAdded)
    {
        base.SaveSessionID(context, id, out redirected, out cookieAdded);

        if (cookieAdded)
        {
            SessionStateSection sessionStateSection = (System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
            var cookie = context.Response.Cookies[sessionStateSection.CookieName];
            cookie.Path = context.Request.ApplicationPath;
        }
    }
}
```

And update the web.config as follows;

```
<sessionState sessionIDManagerType="ANJU.Reports.WebUI.Library.CookieManager" timeout="30" cookieName="CookieName"/>
```

Now when I host my application on the IIS, it'll fetch the directory where I have my build.
All my cookies will point to the root directory of the build.

Answer (score 0):

please try to change the URL from http://www.website/login/ to http://www.website/forms/login/ and then you can see the cookie will send in the request header, and you will auto login.

This is caused by you change the cookie URL to /forms, it means that only the http URL has /forms string will send the session cookie which has created with the aspnet_sessionID.

If you don't change the cookie URL, default path '/' means the cookie can be shared.

You can see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie.path?view=netframework-4.8